# Creating custom element without using class keyword

Tags: javascript, web-component, es6-class, custom-element

This is actually more a question about the object-orientation model in ES6. However I am going to use the creation of a new custom element as an example.

So the new and shiny (as of today) method to create a new custom element is via `customElements.define()` which take in a tag `name`, a `constructor`, and `options` (which is optional) according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/define), [Google](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/architecture/building-components/customelements), and of course the [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-element-conformance). All the documentation listed uses a variation of the new `class` keyword for `constructor`.

Assuming I don't like the new `class` syntax, and considering for most part `class` is a syntatic sugar (according to [this tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/better-javascript-with-es6-pt-ii-a-deep-dive-into-classes)). The spec even specifically state that

> A parameter-less call to `super()` must be the first statement in the
>   constructor body, to establish the correct prototype chain and this
>   value before any further code is run.

By reading the tutorial I came out with this to try if it is possible (also to revise and re-learn Javascript's object model).

```
var _extends = function(_parent) {
    var _result = function() {
        _parent.call(this);
    };
    _result.prototype = Object.create(_parent.prototype);
    Object.defineProperty(_result.constructor, 'constructor', {
        enumerable: false,
        writeable: true,
        value: _result
    });

    return _result;
};

customElements.define('foo-bar', _extends(HTMLElement));
console.log(document.createElement('foo-bar'));
```

I am getting this error

> Error: The custom element being constructed was not registered with
>   `customElements`.

So my question is, is it possible to do it without using `class` keyword (also without `new` if possible)? If the answer is no, should I stick to the `class` keyword instead of using `Object.create` when I write new Javascript code in the future?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In some simple situations it is possible to define a custom element without the `class` keyword.

The trick is to use `Reflect.construct()` to replace the `super()` call.

```
var CEo = function ()
{
    console.log( "created" )
    return Reflect.construct( HTMLElement, [], CEo )
}

CEo.prototype = Object.create( HTMLElement.prototype )

CEo.prototype.connectedCallback = function ()
{
    console.log( "connected" )
    this.innerHTML = "Hello v1"
} 

customElements.define( "object-v1", CEo )
```

Note that it's a not a supported syntax because, as you stated, ES6 classes are a little more than just syntaxic sugar.

Comment: LOL, that's good to know. Nah, not gonna do that, I don't feel like explaining why it works this way to future collaborators. Guess from now on I write only `class` to avoid confusion.

Comment: At first I tried to define custom elements with Object instead of class but in the end I had to switch to class anyways...

Comment: this prompted me to go back and revise/relearn the object model in javascript ):